# Execution Failed for task in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build-error

Does anyone faced this kind of error. I tried things from other posting but nothing worked.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileBetaConfigDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$MethodSymbol cannot be cast to javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
 ndency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
<a href="syncProject">Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</a></li><li>The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem. Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)</a></li>
<li>Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
</li></ul>In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

Help me out. Thanks in advance.

Note: this started happening after i adding retrofit to my project. I have Picasso library also from square sitting in my gradle dependency.